# Is there a way to get the guild's notification settings?

Tags: python, discord, notifications, discord.py

For example, whenever a user uses the `!notification` command, it should print in the console whether the server's notification settings are set to `"all messages"` or `"only @mentions"`.

Here is an idea of what I'd like to use it for.

```python
@bot.command()
async def notification():
  notificationsettings = # Notification settings here

  if notificationsettings == "only @mentions":
    print("You'll only get mention notifications")

  else:
    print("You'll get every message notifications")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Guild's notification level can be found through the `Guild.default_notifications` attribute. This will return a [`NotificationLevel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.NotificationLevel) object.